# Properly mapping through a JSON in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

Noob here, I'm trying to digitize a game book, which I have converted into a JSON, called content. The format is as follows:

```
{
     "123" : {
        "content": "something happens",
        "options": [
            [12, "Go to 12"],
            [13, "Go to 13"]
        ]
    },
}
```

What happens here is that the current location being chapter 123, you read the text and have buttons for 2 options, either go to chapter 12, or chapter 13.

My component looks as following, and everything works well in JavaScript:

```
function Chapters({ chapter }: Content) { 

  return (
    <div>
       {content[chapter].content.split("\n").map((line: string, index: number) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          {line}
          <br />
          <br />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))
      }
      
      {content[chapter].options.map((option: Option) => (
        <button>{option[1]}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However I'm helpless in making TypeScript understand that when I'm mapping the content with the chapter prop from a higher component:

```
const [chapter, setChapter] = useState(123)
```

I'm not referring to the entire block of JSON, but only to its key (which should normally be parsed into an integer).

How can I make TS make this distinction?

PS In case it matters, my current type for the JSON file is this:

```
export type Content = {
    [key: string | number]: {
        content: string,
        options: Option[]
    }
}

export type Option = {
    0: number,
    1: string,
}
```

I'm trying to make TypeScript take the string keys of a JSON file as numbers.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDE to see what you're seeing, including importing any dependencies you need (and maybe tagging the question with those dependencies if they're third-party frameworks like react, etc)

Comment: Your Option type looks like it was written in a version before tuples were introduced. It can be written as `[number, string]`.